# If the square of a natural number is odd then this number is odd.

Tags: proof-explanation, square-numbers

My book says that

> We represent $n$ as $n=2k+1$ where $k$ is from natural numbers or $k=0$
>
> Then $n^2=(2k+1)^2=4k^2+4k+1$.
>   We write $n^2=2(2k^2+2k)+1$ where $2k^2+2k$ is natural number or $0$ and we write it with $k_1$.
>
> Now we can say that $n^2=2k_1+1$ where $k_1$ is a natural number or $0$. 
>   This proves what we wanted to know.

Now I don't get the last part of proof when we replaced the $2k^2+2k$. Can anyone help me?

Comment: All it is showing is that $n^2$ is $2$ times something (even) plus $1$ (odd). The $2k^2+2k$ is renamed to $k_1$ just to make it look neater.

Comment: Also, you can prove this by contraposition.  Suppose you start with an even number.  Then it's easy to show that 4 divides the square of this number.... in particular, 2 divides the square, so the square of the number is even.

Comment: To expand on what Regret was saying: $$n^2 = 2\underbrace{(2k^2 + 2k)}_{\text{call this }k_1} + 1$$

Answer (score 1):

The proof presented by your book actually proves the converse of the statement in the title:

> If a number is odd, then the square of that number is odd.

As hinted in the comments, a quick way to prove the original statement in your title is to prove its contrapositive instead.

> If a number is even, then the square of that number is even.

Answer (score 0):

**An other way :**

Let $n=p_1\cdot ...\cdot p_m$ the prime decomposition of $n$. Since 
$$n^2=p_1^2\cdot ...\cdot p_m^2$$
is odd, $2$ don't divide any $p_i^2$, and thus $2$ don't divide any $p_i$ since $2\mid p_i\implies 2\mid p_i^2$. Therefore, $2$ don't divide $n$ and thus $n$ is odd.